# Clip Path Flutter: How to cut background in such shape using clip path widget? "Image Attached"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, clip-path

Here is the Required Output Picture

[image: Click Here]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet what you've tried so far?  You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://shapemaker.web.app/#/

this website solved my problem in minutes, try it whenever you need a shape using CLIPPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and not finding anything, i did get the answer somehow, i used the an online available tool [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) it automatically generate the values for any shape you draw on the editor it provides.